# How can NFL legally suspend players for off field actions

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl, suspension

Inspired by the deflate gate and Ezekiel Elliott's now halted suspension, I'm wondering how the NFL can legally suspend players for off the field behaviours. Are there clauses in the contracts and CBA that specifically mention such situations?

In the case of Ezekiel Elliott, he didn't even get charged by the police for domestic violence (please correct me if I'm misinformed), so on what bases did the commissioner Goodell suspend him?

Comment: Related: [What is the legal basis for fining players for out-of-game actions?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/what-is-the-legal-basis-for-fining-players-for-out-of-game-actions) is essentially the same thing, but just a slightly different clause in the CBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually covered by the standard NFL player contract; the wording for this can be found in Appendix A of the [NFL Collective Bargaining Agreement](https://nfllabor.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/collective-bargaining-agreement-2011-2020.pdf), specifically Clause 15 of that contract, "Integrity of the Game" (pages 261-262):

> Player therefore acknowledges his awareness that if he [...] is guilty of any other form of conduct reasonably judged by the League Commissioner to be detrimental to the League or professional football, the Commissioner will have the right [...] to fine Player in a reasonable amount; to suspend Player for a period certain or indefinitely; and/or to terminate this contract.